# What type of locks are needed when creating a Postgres index concurrently?

Tags: postgresql, index, locking

I know that when an index is being created concurrently, only a <strike>SHARE</strike> ShareUpdateExclusiveLock lock is needed.

But is there a more strict type of lock needed at the very start of the process for a small amount of time? Or is only a <strike>SHARE</strike> ShareUpdateExclusiveLock lock needed for the entire operation?

I'm asking because I'm wondering what types of timeouts are advantageous to set when creating an index concurrently.

Comment: Discussion in PG Slack here: https://postgresteam.slack.com/archives/C0FS3UTAP/p1606863006250500

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, when documentation is not enough it is possible to looking directly in code. I will give links to already released `PostgreSQL 13.1` (`REL_13_1` tag) in order to avoid possible line number changes in future.

I probably will not describe the entire code path of the command from the client. By grammar we know that we need [`IndexStmt`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_1/src/backend/parser/gram.y#L7409) command node - same grammar for both concurrently and non-concurrently create index. Everything useful will start in [`ProcessUtilitySlow`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_1/src/backend/tcop/utility.c#L1451)

And here, in comment to `case T_IndexStmt`, can be found direct answer for question:

```
/*
 * .... To avoid lock upgrade hazards, it's
 * important that we take the strongest lock that will
 * eventually be needed here, so the lockmode calculation
 * needs to match what DefineIndex() does.
 */
lockmode = stmt->concurrent ? ShareUpdateExclusiveLock
    : ShareLock;
```

In general PostgreSQL will do not upgrade lock during command execution. And will take the strongest lock that will eventually be needed. For `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` it's `ShareUpdateExclusiveLock`. Not a `SHARE` lock as mentioned in question.

But let's continue reading:

- in case of partitioned table `find_all_inheritors` will acquire same lockmode on inheritors.
- in [`transformIndexStmt`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_1/src/backend/parser/parse_utilcmd.c#L2719) can be found some locking modes, but `NoLock` and `AccessShareLock` - they are weaker than `ShareUpdateExclusiveLock`
- in [`DefineIndex`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_1/src/backend/commands/indexcmds.c#L455) we see another reminder:

```
     * To avoid lock upgrade hazards, that lock should be at least
     * as strong as the one we take here.
```

And decide to take againg ShareUpdateExclusiveLock for concurrently build. This part of the code is noticeably long (still not as large as, for example, planner), but readable.

---

I am missing something? Probably. So let's build PostgreSQL with `-DLOCK_DEBUG` option to debug locking behavior and see that happens:

```
./configure  --prefix=/home/melkij/tmp/pgdev/inst --enable-cassert --enable-debug CFLAGS="-ggdb -Og -g3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DLOCK_DEBUG" --enable-tap-tests
make -sj 4
make install
initdb ...
pg_ctl start ...
# then psql with follow commands
create table foo as select generate_series(1,1000) as id;
set trace_locks = true;
create index concurrently on foo (id);
select oid, relname, relkind from pg_class where oid in (16387,16393);
#  oid  |  relname   | relkind 
#-------+------------+---------
# 16387 | foo        | r
# 16393 | foo_id_idx | i
```

`trace_locks` will log many things, but we are interested in:

```
[vxid:3/62 txid:0] [CREATE INDEX] LOG:  LockAcquire: lock [12664,16387] ShareUpdateExclusiveLock
[vxid:3/62 txid:0] [CREATE INDEX] LOG:  LockAcquire: lock [12664,16387] ShareUpdateExclusiveLock
[vxid:3/62 txid:0] [CREATE INDEX] LOG:  LockAcquire: lock [12664,16393] AccessExclusiveLock
[vxid:3/62 txid:495] [CREATE INDEX] LOG:  LockAcquire: lock [12664,16387] ShareUpdateExclusiveLock
[vxid:3/63 txid:0] [CREATE INDEX] LOG:  LockAcquire: lock [12664,16387] ShareUpdateExclusiveLock
[vxid:3/63 txid:0] [CREATE INDEX] LOG:  LockAcquire: lock [12664,16393] RowExclusiveLock
[vxid:3/64 txid:0] [CREATE INDEX] LOG:  LockAcquire: lock [12664,16387] ShareUpdateExclusiveLock
[vxid:3/64 txid:0] [CREATE INDEX] LOG:  LockAcquire: lock [12664,16393] RowExclusiveLock
[vxid:3/64 txid:0] [CREATE INDEX] LOG:  LockAcquire: lock [12664,16393] ExclusiveLock
[vxid:3/64 txid:0] [CREATE INDEX] LOG:  LockAcquire: lock [12664,16393] ExclusiveLock
```

`lock [12664,16387]` here means database `OID = 12664`, `pg_class` `OID = 16387` (such rows are logged from [`LockAcquireExtended`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_1/src/backend/storage/lmgr/lock.c#L757)).

So, we actually acquire only `ShareUpdateExclusiveLock` on table itself. `OID=16393` with several other locks is the index that this command built. Although heavy locking levels are mentioned for this object, it will not interfere with other queries. `Create index concurrently` command is specially designed to work safely while running normal application queries.

Comment: Wow, epic answer, amazing, thank you so much! I understood everything except the very last sentence. "OID=16393 was a just builded index, it will not conflict with queries." - what do you mean "a just builded index"?

Comment: My English is bad, sorry. I will rephrase this sentence.

Comment: your english is great! thanks again